# In what cases multiple port (socket) server is better regarding performance?

Tags: sockets, server

Under what conditions it's more suitable for server to listen on *multiple* ports?

Comment: Interesting, never thought in this direction, +1! Waiting for a nice answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think multiple sockets will result in any performance boost - unless the machine you use to run your application has several network interfaces in use. The real bottleneck is network latency, and sockets are just an abstraction, they can't do much here.

So, choose the amount of ports you want to use based on app requirements. I would better think of organizing socket IO in threads or processes:

**When you send/receive/wait for data, do you block anything from working?**

Comment: _"I would better think of organizing socket IO in threads or processes"_ - a thread, let alone a process per connection does not scale well.

Comment: @CodeCaster sure, I'm just not going into details here. One may use several processes/threads sometimes (like in nginx or apache), but I agree, a thread should be enough for most applications.